# Open http target in another tab and pass data to server at the same time

Tags: http, go, post

What I'd like is for a user to click a `hyperlink` or a `button` so that two things happen:

1- the request is read by the server and subsequent operations can be done:

a) update the database

b) serve the same webpage (although with the applied record off)

2- open a new tab with the target URL

With a `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">apply</a>`  I can accomplish 2, but not 1.

In a template file, if there's:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="appl- {{- .ID}}" name="applied" value="{{.ID}}">
<label for="appl- {{- .ID}}">Applied</label>
```

the data is passed to the server, so 1 is done, but cannot accomplish 2.

Is there a way to do both operations?

Comment: I think the optimal way to achieve what you're trying to do would be to use some javascript and an AJAX request. Post your form with AJAX then open a new tab programmatically on success.

Comment: [form supports the target attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Attributes). It works the same way as on the a element. `<form target="_blank">`